How to run pytorch inside docker containers on two GCP VM?
I have two GCP VM. on two vms, I run docker container.
I run
docker run --gpus all -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash -p 8000:8000 -p 7860:7860 -p 29500:29500 lf
I am trying llama-factory.
In one container, I run
FORCE_TORCHRUN=1 NNODES=2 RANK=1 MASTER_ADDR=34.138.7.129 MASTER_PORT=29500 llamafactory-cli train examples/train_lora/llama3_lora_sft_ds3.yaml,
where 34.138.7.129 is external ip of vm
In the other container, I run
FORCE_TORCHRUN=1 NNODES=2 RANK=0 MASTER_ADDR=34.138.7.129 MASTER_PORT=29500 llamafactory-cli train examples/train_lora/llama3_lora_sft_ds3.yaml.
But I got
[rank1]: torch.distributed.DistBackendError: NCCL error in: ../torch/csrc/distributed/c10d/ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:1970, unhandled system error (run with NCCL_DEBUG=INFO for details), NCCL version 2.20.5
[rank1]: ncclSystemError: System call (e.g. socket, malloc) or external library call failed or device error. 
[rank1]: Last error:
[rank1]: socketStartConnect: Connect to 172.17.0.2<49113> failed : Software caused connection abort
E0924 21:26:39.866000 140711615779968 torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/api.py:826] failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 484) of binary: /usr/bin/python3.10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/torchrun", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 347, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 879, in main
    run(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 870, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 132, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 263, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError: 
============================================================
/workspace/LLaMA-Factory/src/llamafactory/launcher.py FAILED
------------------------------------------------------------
Failures:
  <NO_OTHER_FAILURES>
------------------------------------------------------------
Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
  time      : 2024-09-24_21:26:39
  host      : 71af1f49abe3
  rank      : 1 (local_rank: 0)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 484)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html
============================================================

it seems that pytorch is using the docker container ip instead of gcp vm external ip.
How to fix this?

You should avoid trying to use the public IPs unless it is necessary for the services to be publicly accessible (in which case you likely need to create|revise firewall rules to permit traffic to the instances' ports). It is more secure is to use the non-routable (private) IP(s).

Check ip addr in your docker container:
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
link/ether 22:23:6b:28:6b:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
inet6 fe80::a402:65ff:fe86:bba6/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Use that IP for your docker container.

I forgot to add --network host when running the docker container.
After adding this, it works. external IPs are used instead of docker ip.
